# Stripe Charge Card via HTTP Rest API

Tags: rest, stripe-payments

I am attempting to charge a card via Stripe but am getting:

```
{ error: 
   { type: 'invalid_request_error',
     message: 'You must supply either a card or a customer id' } }
```

Below is in the body (assume api key is correctly in header, content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, it is a post request to https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges)

```
data = {
  "amount": 400,
  "currency": "usd",
  "card": {
    "number": "4242424242424242",
    "exp_month": "12",
    "exp_year": "2019",
    "cvc": "442"
  },
  "description": "Charge for test@example.com"
}
```

Any idea why this isn't working? Is it formatted incorrectly? Can't find an example of doing it this way in Stripe Documentation. Can charging a card be done directly like this, or is a token required? If so, how can this be done via HTTP and not stripe.js?

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to send that `data` object? That looks like JSON, not a urlencoded form.

Comment: @ceejayoz doh! that's why, thank you!